# Como inserir email e senha dentro dos input dentro do Iframe?

Tags: javascript, login, iframe, dom

Quero saber como inserir um valor dentro do campo de texto dentro de um IFrame.

Por exemplo, [neste link](http://simples.cenofisco.com.br/), existe um login simples. Nele, meu chefe pediu para eu fazer o iframe e deixar tudo digitado automaticamente, somente para ele clicar no OK. Tipo um login automático

Como é o iframe:

```
<iframe id="cenofiscoFrame" src="http://simples.cenofisco.com.br/" width="100%" height="600px" >
```

A única coisa que preciso é que alguém me explique como fazer para inserir o texto no input dentro do iframe!

Também não precisa se preocupar, isso é uma página somente dele, não precisa se preocupar por conter informação "sensível" visível. Se alguém tiver alguma ideia válida também pode falar!!!

Comment: Mas você quer pegar os valores que foram digitados nos campos ou quer preenchê-los automaticamente?

Comment: Automaticamente, tipo deixa uma string ali pronta e só joga no campo dentro do iframe @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Então você não deveria estar atribuindo um valor aos `value` no lugar de obtê-los?

Comment: Como assim, pode dar uma ajuda sou iniciante @AndersonCarlosWoss, como eu atribuo então?

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir de forma simples o que você quer, mas seria algo como `conteudoIframe.Login.value = "admin"`.

Comment: Infelizmente, ainda não foi. Está certo dessa maneira do script que eu estou tentando fazer? @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: @user74651 só o seu chefe irá usar o iframe?

Comment: Sim somente ele, é que ele é preguiçoso. Pq? @HENRIQUELOBO

Comment: @user74651 porque não é recomendado fazer isso, segurança zero.

Comment: Coloquei algumas outras informações, na pergunta @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: "Também não precisa se preocupar, isso é uma página somente dele, não precisa se preocupar por conter informação "sensível" visível" @HENRIQUELOBO

Comment: Acredito que não seja possível, também não é recomendável @AndersonCarlosWoss